# How do daily commuters renew their passports?

Tags: passports

The information on renewing a U.S. Passport seems to say that it takes several weeks to renew unless you have a “life or death emergency”. It also seems that you need to give them your old passport while they process it. What do daily cross-border commuters do? It seems like you have to be without a passport for a while.

Comment: Cross which border? By what method of travel?

Comment: Either the USA-Canada border or the USA-Mexico border, can't matter much. I would answer this for bus (Detroit) and car. It's clear and not too broad.

Comment: @chx We've had better-focused questions before, e.g. [How do I cross US-Canada border while my (US) passport is being renewed?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39100/3221)

Comment: Daily commuters will generally use some sort of border-crossing card (nexus, enhanced driver's license, etc).