# Traveling to Canada by Car from U.S. without Passport and re-entering U.S. by car without passport?

Tags: usa, passports, canada, borders, nexus

I am looking to drive with a friend to Toronto this coming weekend for a basketball game.

My U.S. passport is expired but I have a valid Drivers License and Birth Certificate.

Will I be able to get into Canada with what I have, and will I be able to get back into the U.S.?

Comment: If you have an [Enhanced Driver's License](https://www.dhs.gov/enhanced-drivers-licenses-what-are-they), the answer is "yes," otherwise, the answer is "yes, but"; see *[Can I cross the USA-Canada border with a birth certificate and a passport locator number?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13867)* and *[How do I cross US-Canada border while my (US) passport is being renewed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39100/)*