# Can I cross the US/Canadian border with a copy of my US passport?

Tags: passports, canada, us-citizens

Can I cross the US/Canadian border with a copy of my passport? We left originals at our house in Florida because we didn't think we'd be going to Canada, but we'd like to go to Niagara Falls for a day.

Comment: Uh, no. (if it were allowed, it would defeat the purpose of having security features). If you had an enhanced driver's licenses, that would work, but I don't think Florida has those yet.

Comment: Whilst not exactly the same some of the answers in http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13867/1820 will be informative

Comment: Why not go to Niagara and just stay on the US side?  Or, if you're feeling adventurous, go to the border and show them what ID you do have and say, we didn't plan to be in the area, so we left our passports at home.  I doubt you'll get across, but you might, and you won't lose anything for trying.

Comment: @phoog Except potentially being denied entry into Canada, which may cause problems in the future.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know a couple of people who were denied entry into Canada because they presented insufficient documentation at the border.  Neither had any trouble in subsequent attempts to enter the country.  It's not like you're trying to defraud anyone.

Comment: What if you were allowed into Canada, but now allowed to return to the US?

Comment: In a situation like this Canada allows you to withdraw your request for entry, which doesn't count against you in the future as you were never actually refused entry.  A US citizen can never be refused entry into the US, regardless of a lack of documentation.  The issues becomes proving you are a citizen, which can be done but takes time.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer: NO

The long answer: To enter Canada from the USA as a US citizen you need to produce the actual passport or an enhanced drivers license or a standard drivers license plus birth certificate.

The return to the USA you need your passport or enhanced drivers license.

Photocopies of passports are not legal documents for crossing a border, as they could be easily forged.

Florida does not issue an enhanced drivers license yet, even though they do now require you to prove yourself to be a legal resident of the states.

You are pretty much limited to viewing the falls from the US side.

Comment: Also, in case it is not clear, [passport cards](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/information/card.html) without the passport book can be used, but only for ground travel.

Comment: "To enter Canada from the USA as a US citizen you need to produce the actual passport or an enhanced drivers license or a standard drivers license plus birth certificate." Not true. To enter Canada it is sufficient to produce sufficient documentation to prove the person's identity and U.S. citizenship, which does not need to be those things.

Comment: "The return to the USA you need your passport or enhanced drivers license." Yes, but if you don't, a U.S. citizen cannot be denied entry to the U.S. under any circumstances anyway, as long as they can sufficiently prove their U.S. citizenship.

Comment: @user102008 - Why not post a comment with details to help the OP, rather than simply attacking my reply as being wrong,  Be a contributor not a detractor.