# Leaving the US with birth certificate

Tags: legal, canada, us-citizens, paperwork, minors

I have a daughter five months old has no US passport can she go to Canada with her birth certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I cross the USA-Canada border with a birth certificate and a passport locator number?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13867/can-i-cross-the-usa-canada-border-with-a-birth-certificate-and-a-passport-locato)

Comment: @Karlson Not sure if this is a duplicate: this OP doesn't have a passport locator number. The answer is the same though.

Comment: @JoErNanO For the purposes of the answer it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

As a US citizen, you can enter [Canada](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html#_s2a) with a birth certificate.

> If you are a U.S. citizen, ensure you carry proof of citizenship such
> as a passport, **birth certificate**, a certificate of citizenship or
> naturalization, or a Certificate of Indian Status along with photo
> identification. If you are a U.S. permanent resident, ensure you carry
> proof of your status such as a U.S. Permanent Resident Card.

However be careful when returning home, if you're [entering](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/74/%7E/us-citizens---documents-needed-for-entry-into-the-u.s.) by [land or sea](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative), your child can return with a birth certificate, otherwise they need a passport or some other approved travel document

> **What types of documents are accepted for entry into the United States
> via land and sea?**
>
> U.S. and Canadian citizen children under the age of 16 need only
> present a birth certificate or other proof of citizenship. The birth
> certificate can be original, photocopy, or certified copy.

Comment: @DJClayworth I was just going to say, I think the photo ID is for the Certificate of Indian Status only